# Find the line through $(-1,4)$ for which the distance to $(6,3)$ is 5

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, analytic-geometry

This is the question:

> Find the line through $(-1,4)$ for which the distance to $(6,3)$ is $5$

The answer is:

> $y-4=-4/3(x+1)$ and $y-4=3/4(x+1)$

I do not know how to get this answer.

1. Started with finding a line through $(6,3)$ and perpendicular to the line through $(-1,4)$
2. Tried to find the intersection between the two lines
3. Used the equation for the distance between a point and a line.

But I cannot solve it as there are too many unknowns.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to think about this is to consider the circle with $(6,3)$ as the center and radius $5$. 
$$(x-6)^2+(y-3)^2=25$$
Now the lines you are seeking will be tangent lines to this circle from the point $(-1,4)$. So it boils down to finding the equation of the two tangent lines to this circle.

Answer (score 0):

The equation of any line passing through $(-1,4)$ is $$\frac{y-4}{x+1}=m\iff mx-y+m+4=0$$

The distance of $(6,3)$ from this straight line is $$\frac{|6m-3+m+4|}{\sqrt{m^2+(-1)^2}}=\frac{|7m+1|}{\sqrt{m^2+1}}$$ which is $=5$(here)

Squaring we get $$(7m+1)^2=25(m^2+1)\iff 24m^2+14m-24=0$$

Solve for $m$

Comment: Wish I know, the mistake here

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$

> \begin{align}
> y &=4 + m(x + 1)\ \imp\
> \min\braces{\root{\pars{x - 6}^{2} + \braces{\bracks{m\pars{x + 1} + 4}- 3}^{2}}} = 5
> \end{align}

\begin{align}
\min\braces{\pars{x - 6}^{2} + \pars{mx + m + 1}^{2}} = 25
\end{align}
It determines the value of $x$ as a function of $m$ such that:
$$
x = -\,{m^{2} + m - 6 \over m^{2} + 1}
$$

> Then
>   $$
> {\pars{7m + 1}^{2} \over m^{2} + 1} = 25\quad\imp\quad
> \left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcrcr}
> m_{-} & = & -\,{4 \over 3} & \approx & -1.3333
> \\[3mm]
> m_{+} & = & {3 \over 4} & = & 0.75
> \end{array}\right.
> $$

Obviously, there are two lines.
[image]